# De-selecting single Autofilter item using VBA is actually de-selecting ALL items

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Fairly good with VBA but this code is failing. Trying to de-select a single item in an Autofilter field. Instead, it's deselecting all the items in that field. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? In the below snippet, I want the following:

- Show all the #N/A values in Field 24
- Show all the field values in Field 22 EXCEPT "Revenue"
- Show all the field values in Field 8 EXCEPT blanks

But instead, fields 24 and 8 are deselecting all values and not filtering. I've tried adding a forced calculate but that's not doing anything either. Any advice?

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    With Sheets("Expense Data")
        .Activate
        On Error Resume Next
        .ShowAllData
        Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="<>Revenue"
        Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>(blanks)"
        .Calculate
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you found the problem. Just a comment on the `With` statement... you should use your ranges as `.Range("A1").AutoFilter....etc` (note the leading `.` dot), otherwise it evaluates to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter`. That way you don't need (and shouldn't) to use use `.Activate` , and you can run the macro from anywhere (in the `ActiveWorkbook` at least).

Comment: Ahh thanks for noticing that. So normally, I use the period in front of objects within the With statement but sometimes it won’t let me select a range within a sheet unless that sheet is activated. In this case, I meant to use the periods AND activate the sheet but looks like I accidentally forgot the periods. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it...

It's treated as a TEXT filter - so the "<>(blanks)" should just be "<>".

All fixed.